# Conversion from int32 matrix to float

Tags: matlab, type-conversion

I am trying to use a function Treebagger and i am getting this error:

```
??? Error using ==> classregtree.classregtree>classregtree.preparedata at 229
X must be a matrix of floating-point numbers.

Error in ==> TreeBagger.TreeBagger>TreeBagger.init at 1373
            [bagger.X,ynum,bagger.W,classnames,bagger.Y] ...

Error in ==> TreeBagger.TreeBagger>TreeBagger.TreeBagger at 495
            bagger = init(bagger,X,Y,makeArgs{:});

Error in ==> TreeBagger.TreeBagger at 1
classdef TreeBagger
```

To remove the problem, I need to convert `X`, which currently is an `int32` matrix, to a floating-point matrix. I can't find any working method to do this.

> **Syntax for Treebagger:**
>
> ```
> B= Treebagger(40,X,Y);
> ```
>
> X= features
>   Y= actual output

Comment: Why was this tagged with "rdf"?

Comment: Because TReebagger is a function for RDF "random decision forest"

Comment: Ah, I was wondering what the relevant acronym was.  At any rate, the RDF tag on StackOverflow is for "the Resource Description Framework (RDF)[,] … a language for representing information about resources in the World Wide Web.  It is a syntax independent data model that may be serialised in a variety of concrete syntaxes.  RDF is the core data format used on the Semantic Web."  When you add a tag to a StackOverflow question, there should be a brief tooltip describing the tag.  No harm done.

Comment: Oh!Thanks for the tip :) i'll keep that in mind next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually quite simple

```
>> dx = double( x ); % convert x to double (64bits floating point)
>> sx = single( x ); % convert x to single precision floating point (32bits)
```